# Copy Solr Index out of existing Docker container into new Docker Image

Tags: docker, solr

Here is my setup. I have created a basic solr container (version 5.5.5 from official solr [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/solr/)) using docker. In this container I have created some 30000 documents. What I am now trying to do is create a new docker solr image that has these documents in it by default.

I thought I could copy the index out of my existing container and copy it into my new image through the dockerfile. I tried this by copying it out.

```
docker cp my_solr_container:/opt/solr/server/solr/core_name/data .
```

and then in the Dockerfile for my new solr image copying this data folder into the corresponding folder
    COPY --chown=solr:solr data /opt/solr/server/solr/core_name/data/

but when I build the image and try to run it I get the following error:

```
3035 ERROR (coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-1) [   x:Development] o.a.s.c.CoreContainer Error creating core [Development]: Error opening new searcher
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error opening new searcher
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:820)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:658)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:820)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.access$000(CoreContainer.java:90)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:473)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:464)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor$1.run(ExecutorUtil.java:231)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error opening new searcher
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.openNewSearcher(SolrCore.java:1696)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getSearcher(SolrCore.java:1807)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.initSearcher(SolrCore.java:914)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:793)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.index.CorruptIndexException: codec footer mismatch (file truncated?): actual footer=0 vs expected footer=-1071082520 (resource=MMapIndexInput(path="/opt/solr/server/solr/dev/data/index/_33.fdt"))
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.CodecUtil.validateFooter(CodecUtil.java:418)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.CodecUtil.retrieveChecksum(CodecUtil.java:403)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.compressing.CompressingStoredFieldsReader.<init>(CompressingStoredFieldsReader.java:180)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.compressing.CompressingStoredFieldsFormat.fieldsReader(CompressingStoredFieldsFormat.java:121)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene50.Lucene50StoredFieldsFormat.fieldsReader(Lucene50StoredFieldsFormat.java:173)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentCoreReaders.<init>(SegmentCoreReaders.java:117)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentReader.<init>(SegmentReader.java:65)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.ReadersAndUpdates.getReader(ReadersAndUpdates.java:145)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.ReadersAndUpdates.getReadOnlyClone(ReadersAndUpdates.java:197)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.open(StandardDirectoryReader.java:99)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.getReader(IndexWriter.java:435)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.open(DirectoryReader.java:100)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.open(DirectoryReader.java:79)
    at org.apache.solr.core.StandardIndexReaderFactory.newReader(StandardIndexReaderFactory.java:40)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.openNewSearcher(SolrCore.java:1660)
    ... 13 more
3046 ERROR (coreContainerWorkExecutor-2-thread-1) [   ] o.a.s.c.CoreContainer Error waiting for SolrCore to be created
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [Development]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$2.run(CoreContainer.java:502)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor$1.run(ExecutorUtil.java:231)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [Development]
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:833)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.access$000(CoreContainer.java:90)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:473)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:464)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error opening new searcher
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:820)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:658)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:820)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error opening new searcher
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.openNewSearcher(SolrCore.java:1696)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getSearcher(SolrCore.java:1807)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.initSearcher(SolrCore.java:914)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:793)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.index.CorruptIndexException: codec footer mismatch (file truncated?): actual footer=0 vs expected footer=-1071082520 (resource=MMapIndexInput(path="/opt/solr/server/solr/dev/data/index/_33.fdt"))
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.CodecUtil.validateFooter(CodecUtil.java:418)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.CodecUtil.retrieveChecksum(CodecUtil.java:403)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.compressing.CompressingStoredFieldsReader.<init>(CompressingStoredFieldsReader.java:180)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.compressing.CompressingStoredFieldsFormat.fieldsReader(CompressingStoredFieldsFormat.java:121)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene50.Lucene50StoredFieldsFormat.fieldsReader(Lucene50StoredFieldsFormat.java:173)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentCoreReaders.<init>(SegmentCoreReaders.java:117)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentReader.<init>(SegmentReader.java:65)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.ReadersAndUpdates.getReader(ReadersAndUpdates.java:145)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.ReadersAndUpdates.getReadOnlyClone(ReadersAndUpdates.java:197)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.open(StandardDirectoryReader.java:99)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.getReader(IndexWriter.java:435)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.open(DirectoryReader.java:100)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.open(DirectoryReader.java:79)
    at org.apache.solr.core.StandardIndexReaderFactory.newReader(StandardIndexReaderFactory.java:40)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.openNewSearcher(SolrCore.java:1660)
    ... 13 more
```

I also tried to copy the index in another fashion by hitting the url

```
http://host:8080/solr/replication?command=backup&location=/home/backup
```

on my existing container, then copying down the backup index from the container and copying into my new docker image in the same way but ran into the same error.

What would be a possible way to copy data from my existing container such that I can build a new image with this data already set.

Here is my Dockerfile for reference as well:

```
FROM solr:5.5.5

ARG core_name="Development"
ARG core_path="/opt/solr/server/solr/dev"

COPY --chown=solr:solr schema.xml $core_path/conf/
COPY --chown=solr:solr solrconfig.xml $core_path/conf/
COPY --chown=solr:solr stopwords.txt $core_path/conf/

COPY --chown=solr:solr data $core_path/data/



USER solr
RUN echo "name=$core_name" > $core_path/core.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use `[docker commit][1]` to just commit the container instance where you have created the documents as a new image.